# Googlesheets, script to create duplicate tab with new month name, not copying data forward

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I am using to create new data for a project which tracks client information monthly. I've assigned it to a button, and when that button is clicked, it takes a current previous month's tab (in this example, May 2022), and creates a new tab called Jun 2022.

```
function New_month_tab()
{
  var monthNames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var monthsToAdd = 1;
  var currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + monthsToAdd);

  var sheetName = monthNames[currentDate.getMonth()]+" "+currentDate.getFullYear();
  var sheetsArray = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var creationFlag = false;
  //Logger.log(sheetsArray)
  for(var itr in sheetsArray)
  {
    if(sheetsArray[itr].getSheetName() == sheetName)
    {
      creationFlag = false;
      break;
    }
    else
      creationFlag = true;
  }

  if(creationFlag)
    spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);

  if(!creationFlag)
    Logger.log("Worksheet Exists");

}//New_month_tab
```

My script is not copying the data from the May 2022 tab into the newly created Jun 2022 tab. I need it to do this, and also copy the formatting (so that it prints appropriately). How can my script be adjusted to do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to copy all the data from the previous tab to the new one, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To duplicate the tab you need to use `duplicateActiveSheet()` instead of `insertSheet()`, so this line:

```
spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
```

Should go like this:

```
spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet().setName(sheetName);
```